# Clear image background and remove vertical line

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to clear vertical line and other black spot which is near to number.

Here is my Input image:-
[image]

I tried below command but it's remove vertical line but also cut number and  still black spot there.

```
convert in.png -write mpr:ORG \( +clone -negate -morphology Erode rectangle:60x1 -mask mpr:ORG -morphology Dilate rectangle:60x1 +mask \) -compose Lighten -composite out.png
```

[image]

is it possible via single command to remove that black vertical line (but number can not cut) and other black spot? I need result 17.75.

Comment: This is not an answer, is just a pointing for a very interesting framework: [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) is a library that it's used for images and video manipulation. In the section of *learning* in the link I just give you are many interesting tutos about the images manipulation. Hope you can find some guidance.

Comment: @ k.Cyborg : i am using php and i didn't have idea about openCv if you have any reference link then please provide me.

Comment: I'm leaving you some links: [Tutos for Python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (I know, It's not what you're looking for, just wait), [OpenCV for PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP) and [a question with some interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002895/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-opencv-with-php). I recommend  you to pass over the first link I give you, it's in *Python*, but it will give some (needed) general idea about the usage of *OpenCV*